# Dataweave: Match Regex Pattern to each element of Array

Tags: arrays, loops, dataweave

I have an array ["NJK","NST","NIR"] I want to iterate over it and match each element of it with this pattern /^N.*[^1]$/ (Starts with N and doesn't end with 1) and return 'true' even if one such occurrence is present. How do I iterate over the array using dataweave?

Comment: Hi, @Amer Sufi! What is you expected output? Are you trying to convert the array to something else, or trying to execute some action based on each matched array item?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **`matches`** to match your REGEX pattern.

**Option 1:** (This will replace the item with boolean if it matched the pattern you have.)

**Input:**

```
%dw 2.0
import * from dw::core::Arrays
var sample = ["NJK","NST","NIR"]
output application/json
---
sample map ($ matches /^N.*[^1]$/ )
```

**Output:**

```
[
  true,
  true,
  true
]
```

---

**Option 2:** (If you want to check if any of the item is **`matched`** and only return a single boolean, you can use the **`some`** )

**Input:**

```
%dw 2.0
import * from dw::core::Arrays
var sample = ["NJK","NST","NIR"]
output application/json
---
sample some ($ matches /^N.*[^1]$/ )
```

**Output:**

```
true
```

---

**Option 3:** You can also use the **NOT isEmpty** combination with **matches** ***(ie: `!isEmpty(<expression>)`)***.

**Input:**

```
%dw 2.0
var sample = ["NJK","NST","NIR"]
output application/json
---
!isEmpty(sample[?($ matches /^N.*[^1]$/ )])
```

**Output:**

```
true
```

---